# iOS simulator working fine but real device not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

Today I would like to run my app on my iPhone 12 Pro Max (iOS 14.7.1). This is the error I'm facing right now when trying to debug.

It is working fine on iPhone 12 Pro Max simulator (iOS 14.5). I have no idea what is the problem.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Yen’s iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: M3Z8JK21AX
Xcode build done.                                           43.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

2021-08-24 15:49:28.226 xcodebuild[73295:9223794]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-00064D483604001E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f8e99baaba0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8e998c4210>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2021-08-24 15:49:28.434 xcodebuild[73295:9223785]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-00064D483604001E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f8e99baaba0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8e96e1a6c0>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2021-08-24 15:49:28.516 xcodebuild[73295:9223785]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-00064D483604001E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f8e99baaba0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8e96e1a6c0>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/YeN/Desktop/cmg projects/gmg/ios/Pods/Reachability/Reachability.m:465:63: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'unsigned int' from 'Reachability *' [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
NSStringFromClass([self class]), (unsigned int) self, [self currentReachabilityFlags]];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
2 warnings generated.
/Users/YeN/Desktop/cmg projects/gmg/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:168:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/YeN/Desktop/cmg projects/gmg/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
1 warning generated.
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Yen’s iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Package ```'openURL:``` is depricated. Use this: ```open_url: ^2.0.0```

Comment: I don't have this package `open_url`

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/open_url .. You can find any any package here. https://pub.dev/

Comment: in the error message it is showing. ```^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
2 warnings generated.
/Users/YeN/Desktop/cmg projects/gmg/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:168:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
^~~~~~~```

Comment: I suggest you update the flutter package.. and Xcode